# to convert list to integer and store it in csv file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I have some data generated in a list. I have created a csv file and it appends data in csv file.But I need to store the data as integer/string not as a list. My code is below:

```
VALUE = list(map(int, VALUE))
print(name, VALUE)
with open("data.csv", "a") as out_file:
        out_string =  ""
        out_string +=  "" + name
        out_string +=  "," + str(VALUE)
        out_string += "\n"
        out_file.write(out_string)
```

The output file is: [image]

I need to remove the `[` and `]` generated in column 2 and 17. I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Replace `"," + str(VALUE)` by `", ".join(VALUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing an array of integers, which looks like this:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> print(str(x))
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

The square brackets are Python's way to print an array.  To print them as CSV lines, convert the elements to strings, and join them with a comma:

```
out_string +=  "," + ",".join([str(i) for i in VALUE])
```

Answer (score 1):

When `VALUE` (why uppercase, it's not a constant?) ist a `list` with two elements of type `int` and values `153` and `42`, `str(VALUE)` will be `[153,42]`. When you want the output to be `153,42`, you can use `','.join(VALUE)` which will concatenate the elements of the list, separated by the `str` on which you call the `join` method, in this case the comma.

When writing `.csv` files, however, you might also want to consider using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module from the Python standard library.

Answer (score 0):

The data type of your `out_string` is list in your case and it is giving you list of list. To convert you can use **join** which will convert the datatype to str and concatenate the elements of list in your case its "**,**".

```
VALUE = list(map(int, VALUE))
print(name, VALUE)
with open("data.csv", "a") as out_file:
    out_string =  ""
    out_string +=  "" + name
    out_string +=  ",".join(VALUE)
    out_string += "\n"
    out_file.write(out_string)`
```

I guess it will now give you the desired output.